# Configuring ADB for Nexus 4 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: adb, linux, nexus-4

I'm trying to deploy and test an Android app on my Nexus 4 from my Ubuntu 11.10 computer, but ADB doesn't recognize it. I think I need the Google USB drivers, but I cannot find instructions on how to install them on Ubuntu.

How can I install the drivers on Ubuntu 11.10 so that ADB will recognize my N4?

Answer (score 16):

You don't need any special drivers -- all you need is to make your device known. A few simple steps can accomplish this when your device is connected via USB:

```
sudo lsusb
[...]
Bus 002 Device 054: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc. Nexus S (debug)
```

See the two hex values separated by a colon: `18d1:4e22` This is the manufacturerID:deviceID you need to tell the system to handle. So as root:

```
sudo su -
cd /etc/udev/rules.d
vi 51-android.rules
```

In this file, add a line (you can use the editor of your choice, of course -- my example uses `vi`)

```
# MyDeviceName
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4e22", MODE="0666" GROUP="androiddev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

This example uses the values from above `lsusb` output -- you need to replace them by yours. Now, to let your changes take effect:

```
sudo service udev reload
```

Final step: Disconnect your device, and reconnect it. It should be recognized now.

Answer (score 3):

As explained at [Enable developer options in Android 4.2 on Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus](http://www.redmondpie.com/enable-developer-options-in-android-4.2-on-nexus-4-and-galaxy-nexus/) you need to activate developer mode.

> Step 1: Pull down the notifications panel on your device’s interface and tap on Settings.
>
> Step 2: Next, scroll all the way down and tap on About Phone, and you will notice a segment detailing your device’s build number.
>
> Step 3: Repeatedly tap on Build Number (seven taps should do the trick) until you’re met with a message that reads: “you are now a developer!”