# adb option like fastboot -i <vendorid>?

Tags: adb, fastboot

Hi I was wondering if there was a command similar to fastboot's `-i` in adb. I'm currently trying to find my device in adb, but I could only target the device in fastboot with `-i` and the vendor id (I got it with `lsusb -v`) and got nothing in adb. I added:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0x1f3a", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

to `/etc/udev/rules.d/android-51.rules` to try and get it to come up in adb but nothing came up in the devices list (I saw on a tutorial that it would make the device show up). Thanks!

Comment: Your final objective is to get the device detected by adb. Correct? And you think the approach in title is the way to go. Right? // Which Android device, version are you using? What OS are you using on PC? // Are you having the same problem noted [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47938/96277)?

Comment: I'm using a Ubuntu (chroot on a Chromebook), and my android version is 4.4.2 Kitkat (I think ill check), and kinda but not the exact same problem.. But close enough that ill look at it, but i don't have ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Comment: I've always just plugged in an android-51.rules file that I find online...  you can modify it if needed to support your device.  Try this one: https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules/blob/master/51-android.rules

Comment: Also, instructions here: https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work pretty fine: `lsusb` (Windows)

and

`lsusb -v` (Linux)