# unlock Xperia Neo bootloader on linux

Tags: linux, usb-drivers, bootloader-lock, android-sdk, sony-ericsson-xperia-neo

I was following [these instructions](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/instructions) to unlock the bootloader on my Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo until I reached steps 9 and 10.

There was no extras/google directory or android_winusb.inf file anywhere. So from Eclipse's Android SDK manager I tried to download the Google USB Driver but found it as not compatible with linux.

What should I do now to replace steps 9 and 10?

Comment: That should be similar to the ADB stuff, see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575). There's no such thing as a "driver install" on Linux.

Comment: [this](http://duopetalflower.blogspot.in/2012/12/unlock-xperia-s-bootloader-from-ubuntu.html) is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both solutions mentioned by @Izzy and @darknight in comments could work, But I found the easiest way is to replace steps 8,9,10 of the instructions by the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

and then continuing as normal (and of course write fastboot instead of fastboot.exe in steps 15,16).

That saves the trouble of manually downloading and installing flashboot and configuring files and so.