# How do I install USB drivers in Ubuntu 13:04 for Nexus S?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, samsung-nexus-s, linux, usb-drivers

I am trying to follow this guide:
   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2163085

However I am unable to connect to my android phone via USB.  I think I need to install the USB drivers for Ubuntu.  I am using Ubuntu 13:04 and the Nexus S currently has Cyanogenmod on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Glen.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) and [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575) to the question [Configuring ADB for Nexus 4 on Ubuntu 11.10](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39431/16575), that should solve your issue. Except, after taking a look at the XDA thread you linked: Are you asking about Ubuntu on your Nexus-S?

Comment: Are you talking about installing the USB driver on your phone, in your new Ubuntu installation, or about installing a USB driver for an Android phone on your desktop PC?

Comment: Dan Hulme,

I am trying to copy files from Ubuntu 13:04 to Cyanogen Mod.  I previously experimented with making an android game that needed USB drivers.  I did all this and was able to copy files via USB.

My Nexus S phone with Cyanogen Mod phone appears to have been hacked gotten a virus or has bug (probably from installing an old version of gapps).

I use to be able to copy files via USB.  Now I cannot.  I am using a new Ubuntu PC with 13:04.

Comment: I have a Nexus 7 and I had the same problem ... try this, just say I don't have the Cyanogenmod install on my Nexus, but you can try. http://askubuntu.com/questions/207569/how-do-i-connect-a-nexus-7-to-transfer-files

Answer (score 2):

As was already pointed out in a number of answers as well as in the comments, one does not need to download/install separate USB drivers for your Android device; they are already compiled into the Kernel.  However, you do have to tell your Linux system what device you want it to treat as such (`udev` rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory).  Take a look at the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

To facilitate the installation of these "**udev rules**", I've set up a github repository with an installation script at https://github.com/ILMostro/Android-Udev-Rules.  You can download it with `git` by typing into the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/ILMostro/Android-Udev-Rules.git
```