# Make a device appear in ADB

Tags: usb, adb, linux

I have a Zen Touch 2, a Cyclone Voyager and a Samsung galaxy Fame, all configured for USB debugging.

I also have a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04, the standard ADB obtained from apt-get, and Fastboot obtained from apt-get.

My problem is that when I plug in my Fame on it's own, I can see it in the list of attached devices when I run the adb devices command. However, when I attach the others, I cannot.

I have plugged them in on their own and tried all 4 different ports. Switching to PTP doesn't work. And it is not just the devices command.

How can I make them appear and allow me to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing **udev** rules for the other device manufacturers?

A rule for samsung is probably included by default.

Look here for instructions http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: why look so far if such beauty is right before your eyes: We have this here [in an answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575) as well :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you neither worked but when put together works fine.