# Make device available in ADB (Windows 8)

Tags: adb, windows

A while back, I asked [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56807/make-a-device-appear-in-adb/56809?noredirect=1#56809) about the ADB. I now have another laptop running windows 8.1 and the problem is the same. Please look at the previous post for details.

Please help