# How do I get my Nexus 5 to show up in the adb devices list?

Tags: usb-debugging, nexus-5

I'm trying to connect my Nexus 5 to DDMS in Eclipse.

When I uncheck Debugger Mode on my Nexus 5, it is detected as MTP.
When I check Debugger Mode on my Nexus 5, it is detected as a USB device and can be ejected.

But it doesn't appear in the DDMS neither with adb -devices

How can I get it to show up in the DDMS?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Serge! We need some more details to answer your question, as solutions are different between operating systems. On Windows, you might need to install a specific driver (e.g. Koush's [universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/)), while on Linux you just need to enter a line in your config (see e.g. [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575)).