# Acer DA241HL - system reset from bootloader

Tags: device-firmware, bootloader

The Acer DA241HL is a 24" Smart Display which has Android installed but also had HDMI input so you can use it as a second screen for a laptop or similar too.

Anyway, I've been able to reboot into the bootloader using adb with the Acer DA241HL connected.

However, it doesn't show up on `fastboot devices` nor `adb devices` and only stays on the boot options screen for about 5 seconds before it seems to turn off completely.

At the top, it explains that pressing  or  allows you to move up/down in the list of options (bootload, restart, shutdown, reboot ? something like that), and then pressing the power button to select the option... however this is not a tablet or a phone, it's a "Smart Display" and the Volume Up/Down options don't do anything but turn the volume up and down for the screen (it's like it's not sending those buttons directly to Android, but only to the screens built-in speakers).

Pressing the power button when on the bootloader doesn't seem to do anything either, I've had to press the power button multiple times before the machine reboots back into Android otherwise it continuously boots into the bootloader and then shuts off after a 5 seconds.

Does anyone know how I can fully system reset (as in roll back all the firmware updates I performed) this device?

I've tried pressing and holding Volume Up with the Power button to boot into the bootloader 'manually' instead of using adb but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: No "reset" will ever roll back any system updates applied. For that, you would have to re-flash the original ROM. For the device to show up with `adb devices` or `fastboot devices`, you must have your computer configured accordingly (Windows needs special drivers, Linux/Mac might be happy with just some configuration settings – see e.g. our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)).

Comment: Ah OK, so I'll need the original firmware... I have quite a few Acer DA241HL that I didn't update, is there a way to copy the ROM/firmware on those and then push to the one I updated? I've been able to use adb just fine and fastboot has worked for other devices, just haven't been able to get the DA241HL to show up for fastboot...

Comment: If they are all the same devices, it should be possible to "dump" the partitions of one device and "flash" them to the others, essentially "cloning" the entire system. But that requires root. You could use either a custom recovery and Nandroid (check our [nandroid tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info) for details), or utilize `dd` for it. I never did that myself, and partition names are quite device specific, so I cannot give detailed help on that.

Comment: OK thanks, well hopefully I'm able to find out how to change the options in the bootloader so I can get to the fastboot option otherwise I can't really do anything with these devices :(

Comment: I've summed up (and detailed) items in a separate answer, to make the facts easier to catch. Good luck, and let us know how it worked out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

1. No "reset" will ever roll back any system updates applied. For that, you would have to re-flash the original ROM.
2. For the device to show up with `adb devices` or `fastboot devices`, you must have your computer configured accordingly. If your computer runs Windows, you will need a special driver (Koush's [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/) might help you out here, in case you cannot find a specific driver for your devices). If it's Linux, you might wish to consult [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575), for a Mac it might be similar. Further helpful hints can be found via our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info).
3. As you have multiple identic devices, some updated and some not, you should be able to utilize `dd` (see also [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) for a starter) to clone all partitions of one device and apply that to others. As partition structures are quite device specific, I cannot give you accurate details here; a little research might be helpful especially on sites like [XDA Developers](http://xda-developers.com/). A custom recovery can be used for this as well: check out our [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) tag and its tag-wiki for details on that.