# Micromax A26 USB Debugging mode Not working

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I am having a Micromax A26. I have enabled the debugging mode of my phone and when trying to root it doesn't show up. One of my friends is a android developer he tried to use my phone for development purpose and he is also not able to detect my phone on android emulator even if the debugging mode is on. Everything else is working. USB data transfer and stuff works. But even if it is enabled debugging mode it doesn't detect. Can some one help me find a solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Having tagged your question `usb-drivers`, are the corresponding drivers installed? What OS you're using?

Comment: I use windows 7.

And my friend used Ubuntu 10.3

Comment: I had installed all the drivers I have obtained from browsing the net for weeks and tried but still doesn't work. Just not sure whether it is the problem of the particular model phone.

Comment: For Win7, you might wish to take a look at Kosh's [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/). Your friend on Linux should know [how to add the device ID](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575) to have it show up (assume he already did that?).

Comment: I will refer this. Mean while i will check with my friend and get back. Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy  I asked my friend and he tried to add the device ID as u said in ubuntu and still not detecting. Must be some manufacturing defect of this phone :( 
Let me try something else. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Tell your friend to try running `adb` as root. I've read a couple of times where this did the trick, for whatever reason. Did it turn up with `lsusb` at all? // Any success with Koush's driver on Win7? And does the device show in Windows' device manager?

Answer (score -2):

I also had this problem, but I solved it for myself. I just needed to change my cable, and it worked again. Maybe you have a defective cable as well.

Comment: I have already tried with different data cable and its not working

Comment: Please change "ur" spelling and avoid things like leet-speak. Here are many non-native-English-speaking participants which already have a "hard time" without that.