# testing an app in htc explorer jelly bean

Tags: android-emulator

I m trying to run the android application project on my phone htc explorer,developers mode on when I run it shows unknown serial number when i check my devices[image: I ma getting an error message when I connect my device and see the console in adt it's not detecting my device]

Comment: As the screenshot looks like you're running Linux: Have you setup ADB correctly? See [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575) for closer hints (though it's on a Nexus question, same steps apply for any Android device).

Comment: yes I'm running linux mint yes it;s configured correctly and I have used the nexus emulator as well it's working

Comment: thank you very much I could use your answer and make my device appear...on my console

Comment: Just wanted to write there might be a difference between "emulator" and "real device" :)

Comment: yeah I tested it on the emulator first now I'm trying it on my htc device

Answer (score 1):

You are basically having a "no permissions" error, where your PC's adb is not able to identify the device that you're connecting. As you said, you have a HTC Explorer, which I do too, with KitKat ;) So here's how you'd be fixing this "no permissions" error:

First, you'd need to create (if inexistent), the `51-android.rules` file. Since you have a HTC Device, we'll just be adding the "rules" for a HTC device, so that your adb can identify your device correctly.

First, obtain superuser permissions using:

```
sudo su
```

and type in your password. Note that you can't see the password being typed, but its still being typed. Then, create the file, if not exists, using the following command:

```
touch /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

This basically creates a 51-android.rules file in the appropriate place, if it doesn't exist.

Now, for adding the rules, we'll just append some text to the file, a correct config, which can be done using the following command:

```
echo "SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ATTR{idVendor}==\"0bb4\", MODE=\"0666\", GROUP=\"plugdev\"" >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

This basically appends the following text, to the 51-android.rules file.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

What the above text is, is the appropriate permissions for a HTC Device.

Now, disconnect your device, kill your adb-server, if running, using

```
adb kill-server
```

and, reconnect device. Now, try running the following command, to see if your device's actually connected :)

```
adb devices
```

You should see an output similar to:

```
List of devices attached
XXXXXXXXXXXX    device
```

Hope this helps :)

P.S.
In case you're searching for rules for other android devices, this link at source.android.com might help: [Initializing a Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). Look for the "[Configuring USB Access](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#configuring-usb-access)" section :)

Also note: 
A better option would be to install the "android-tools-adb" and "android-tools-fastboot" packages available in the Ubuntu repositories.
This can be done using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Comment: ^edited... :) and, this would actually work, for I have the device too :p

Comment: If you've got a different device, see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39431/16575) (includes the steps for how to find the VendorID).

Comment: "a better option": those tools do not automatically create the rules. And to me it looks like OP already has the complete SDK installed, in which case these two packages are redundant, as their tools are already included. // Thanks for your update, Vineeth!