# How do I connect Nexus 5 on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro for USB-debugging

Tags: adb

When I connect my device to my Linux laptop (debian-Ubuntu) I don't get any output in

```
adb logcat
```

If I connect it to another laptop it works fine

in KDE I can open the Directory and copy files, so USB is working

it seems like

```
adb devices
```

finds the device:

```
List of devices attached 
042some_numbers00   device
```

but it stays disconnected somehow

Comment: Have you setup ADB accordingly on that KDE machine?

Comment: thats the question: what is "accordingly"?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39431/16575).

Comment: I tried, but still.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android-mtpfs.rules
```

and added

```
# Nexus 5 (alias Nexus 4) "sudo lsusb" shows: 18d1:4ee2
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4ee2", MODE="0666" GROUP="androiddev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

and I added:

```
echo 0x18d1 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

then I rebooted Ubuntu and it worked!!!