# Error: insufficient permissions for device, how to add permissions?

Tags: tablet, 2.3.3-gingerbread

On trying to install an app on my Reliance CDMA Tablet, this is what happened.

```
aneesh@AcerAOD:~$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions

aneesh@AcerAOD:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions

aneesh@AcerAOD:~$ adb install Dropbox/apks/videolan.apk
error: insufficient permissions for device
- waiting for device -
```

How do I set permissions? I browsed through Development and Security options in Settings application in my tablet. Could someone help me out? Possibly some command line helps! It is a little urgent.

My device runs Android 2.3.3.

Comment: Is the option to enable USB debugging on?  It should be in the same Developer Options section of the settings.

Comment: This is a problem with the permissions on your Linux system, not Android.

Comment: Yes. Debugging was on.

Comment: Have you setup the udev rules correctly on your Linux computer? For a reference, see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575).