# "adb devices" shows device as "unauthorized". How can I fix this?

Tags: adb

I just decided to move from Windows to Linux for my Android development, I just finished to setup Android Studio, I was able to import my project into it, but now I want to be able to run my application on my Google Nexus 5.

In my Android Device Monitor, my phone is detected as unauthorized.

I put :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{18d1}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Into :

```
~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

Comment: You can find your answer here: [Configuring ADB for Nexus 4 on Ubuntu 11.10](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39431/16575). Little different device, so you might have to replace some values – but close enough to solve your issue :)

Comment: That question is not the same as the other. Swann's problem is that he didn't authorized the host to access the device via `adb` (as [answered by keepcalm](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/77591/440)).

Answer (score 3):

You need to [enable USB debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#Enabling) on your phone. You should get prompted to accept an RSA key, which will mean that your computer is authorised.

Also keep in mind that any coding questions belong on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).