# Eclipse is not able to detect smartphone

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, debug

Debian 7.6, Eclipse 3.8.
When i program with API8 for my HTC Froyo I have no problem: running the debug session i see the device in the device list and I'm able to debug my app.
Since I started with a API14 for smartphone and tablet, I'm not able to detect that devices.
When I connect them to the PC i only see ????????? as Serial Number.
If I check the USB connection with `lsusb` or `dmesg`, the devices are detected correctly by the system.
I tested Smartphone LG L5II and Hamlet tablet XZPAD0970H and, of course, the debug option is checked.

I read about a potential problem with permissions but i don't understand how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I found!**
I followed the article [Configuring ADB for Nexus 4 on Ubuntu 11.10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39431/configuring-adb-for-nexus-4-on-ubuntu-11-10) adding a find and a row for my smartphone, inserting its VID e PID. Then I restarted the adb.
Now the smartphone is visible to Eclipse!

Next I'll try with the tablet inserting its VID and PID ..

Comment: I'm very sorry but this morning, when i turned up the system, I have the same original problem  :(  Again ????????? as sn! - I don't understand ...

Comment: The definitive answer: adb tool MUST run as root by 'sudo adb start-server' or by suid-ing the adb file