# How to root from adb?

Tags: adb, root-access

I have a tablet called **General Mobile E-Tab 4**. 
I bricked it. It stays on load animation. I can reach recovery but there are 3 options:

```
reboot device
wipe data/factory reset
wipe cache partition
```

I have pushed root files to `/data/local/tmp` with [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684210) (gave permissions also)

I have also installed VirtualBox and Ubuntu. But I can't see my device in Ubuntu:

[image: Screenshot]

For some reason VM shows me that and never loads:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I also **tried** Droid Explorer, Android Commander and few programs to view tablet's files.

They **saw** the device **but they didn't show it's files.**

I also tried **`mv`** and **`cp`** commands to move root files from `/data/local/tmp` to `/system/bin/sh` but it said:

```
Operation not permitted
```

Same for mount command:

[image: Screenshot]

Also, when sideloading a file from abd, the device gives error: **Installation aborted**

**So what can I do now?**

Comment: Wouldn't your first goal be to unbrick the device – and rooting it *afterwards?* Also, *how* did you brick it? This might give some clues to solving your issue.

Comment: Well, I tried to flash a ROM with Terminal Emulator on device itself. After that, it stays on loading animation.

Comment: so... What can I do now?

Comment: I'd say [edit] your question with the new details (steps performed) would be nice. I'm not sure whether your device is "stuck at boot", or "stuck in a [boot-loop](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) <-- try following up that link and see whether it helps (i.e. if you can boot into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)); if so: have you wiped cache/Dalvik after flashing?

Comment: I did of course but it didn't solve the problem. Because ROM was not completely loaded. I think there is no way to fix this unless sending it to service. They will want money of course because it was rooted and there is a half ROM on it.

Comment: Afraid so. But looking at the screenshots again: the first one shows your device (if ADB doesn't see it, you might need to "configure" it, see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575)). On the second, you have to select what to boot – then it should continue. And one more thing: If you can get a stock ROM (see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)) and have the manufacturer's software for the device, you could try flashing with that.

Comment: My PC sees the device on both mode (device and sideload). But I can push files on device mode. It doesn't push files on sideload and says: device not found. I have the rom of course but there is no tool to flash it. Manufacturer doesn't give it. Because this tablet is for education only...

Answer (score 0):

#### download the SuperSU-UPDATE File

----commands-----

fastboot oem unlock

fastboot flash "SUPERSUFILE"

fastboot reboot