# How can I wipe cache partition in ASUS Fonepad 7 (K00Z) tablet?

Tags: recovery-mode, tablet, asus-fonepad-8

I'm running ASUS Fonepad 7 (K00Z, with KitKat updates installed). Here is what I already tried by referring to [this](http://www.asus-zenfone.com/2015/03/zenfone-2-how-to-enter-recovery-wipe.html) and [this](http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/) guide:

1. I started the phone in `fastboot` bootloader by pressing the `Power + Vol-up` button, but it has only these five options:

   - Reboot.
   - Reboot fastboot.
   - SDCARD Download.
   - Factory Reset.
2. There is no `Recovery mode` where I can delete the cache partition.
3. I also turned on the developer options in settings and then run this command from my linux laptop: `adb reboot recovery`. But the tablet just starts and quits the recovery screen saying "No command found" or something like that.

Is there any hope of being able to delete the cache partition?

**Edit**

The issue is still unresolved, but I went a long way towards learning new things in Android testing, thanks to @Izzy. Primarily,

1. USB Debugging using Android SDK is very helpful. For instance, `adb reboot-bootloader` will restart the phone/tablet to the bootloader. Of course, the device must be recognized by the computer connected through USB which leads to
2. `UDEV rules` should be properly setup (for Linux OS; I'm using I'm using Ubuntu 14.04) or the proper vendor drivers should be installed (for Windows). [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39431/configuring-adb-for-nexus-4-on-ubuntu-11-10/39437?s=2|0.7257#39437) Q/A is very helpful in this regard.
3. `fastboot erase cache` was supposed to help me, but somehow, my ASUS device isn't being recognized by `lsusb` while the tablet is on bootloader screen (and thus, logically, neither by `fastboot devices`). I've raised a ticket about this with ASUS and awaiting a reply from there.

Answer (score -1):

see if this helps :

I installed the temporary custom recovery to root my device, may be you can use that custom recovery to clear the cache.

Search for the methods to root this device.

I will post the link if I can find