# Google Play not responding after CM13 install

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, custom-roms, asus-zenfone-2

Today I installed Cyanogenmod CM13 and Gapps on my Asus Zenfone 2. The install went fine, but when I booted my phone, I selected the language, then when it went to look for updates, a system message appeared "Google Play services has stopped". This has caused the phone to hang at the update page, and to top it off I forgot to install TWRP, so I think I'm going to have an issue installing a fresh install.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What happened**
You don't have TWRP, so your phone is bricked.<sup>**1**</sup>

**How can I unbrick it?**
Look at [this website.](https://www.techmesto.com/recover-bricked-asus-zenfone-2/)

The website tells you

- How to install ADB (which you can also find here on Android.SE: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575), takes less space)
- And unbrick the phone from there. It also gives u the full ROM.

The latter in short requires you to:

- [Download](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices) and install the drivers for your Zenphone on your Windows PC<sup>**2**</sup>
- Get the latest ROM for it (e.g. [Zenfone ZE551ML Stock ROM](http://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone_2_ZE551ML/HelpDesk_Download/) (4GB version) or [Zenfone ZE550ML Stock ROM](http://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone_2_ZE550ML/HelpDesk_Download/) (2GB version))
- use [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) to install that ROM (via "Apply update from ADB", so you can use `adb sideload file.zip` to apply it)

---

<sup>**1:** for installing TWRP, see e.g. [How to Install TWRP Recovery on Zenfone 2 and Root](http://androiding.how/how-to-install-twrp-recovery-on-zenfone-2-and-root/) at Androiding.how. Before that, install the stock ROM and wipe cache+data (from recovery; a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) should do the wipe as well).</sup>
<sup>**2:** not needed on Linux/Mac; for those OSes, see e.g. [Configuring ADB on Ubuntu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39431/16575)</sup>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37603/discussion-between-user2513528-and-lolreppeatlol).

Comment: A booting, working phone with an app issue is not "bricked".

Comment: @MatthewRead However, you can fix it with this guide, so I gave it to him