# ADB is not detecting the device

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, fastboot, usb-drivers

I am running an Ubuntu 14 host machine on my PC and recently I got an *Eragon 820 Development kit* which is running on Android Marshmallow, everything was working fine until I click the factory reset option in the Android settings.

After that the adb / fastboot neither working and In the Dmesg am getting like this

```
[  308.326141] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[  308.420065] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=d001
[  308.420072] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  308.420076] usb 2-1.3: Product: MSM8996 for arm64
[  308.420079] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: unknown
[  308.420083] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 77a941ec
[  310.055562] usb 2-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd adb rqt 128 rq 6 len 256 ret -110
[  311.971228] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 18
```

these same 8 lines keep on repeating (i.e. the device connects, is recognized, some `adb rqt…` fails, device is disconnected again).

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you setup the proper udev rules? See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575) for details. You probably could take the udev rule I've posted there, adjusting `ATTRS{idProduct}=="4e22"` to `ATTRS{idProduct}=="d001"`.

Comment: @lzzy Thank you for your quick replay, yes i already added the the idproduct and vendor id in the 51-android.rules file, but it's not showing the device at adb devices commad

Comment: Looks like the device is having some issues then. Reading the log again with that in mind, it seems Linux tries to apply some ADB command, fails, and disconnects the device (the last 2 lines). You could try another factory-reset, this time from recovery (wipe cache & data) and see if that helps, maybe something was incomplete on the previous run. Not sure if that helps, but worth a try.

Comment: @lzzy Even i loaded a fresh image into it through fastboot mode, but still the device is not booting. Is this due to bootloader is correpted?

Comment: No idea. But if it where corrupted, you couldn't have used fastboot. Btw, the device not booting up is not what your question is about – or at least you didn't mention that. If it's not booted up, the ADB daemon on it might not be started properly, which would explain the issue.

Comment: @lzzy if i manually load the boot image using **fastboot boot boot.img**, the device is starting properly.but if we restart the device again the same issue, the device is booting up

Comment: That sounds as if there's some "corruption" on the boot image (not the boot loader, that's something else). Did you consider flashing a fresh ROM? That might fix it.

Comment: @lzzy , Yes, I flashed a fresh image which is given by the vendor, for that also the same problem. I talk with the vendor directly and they also facing the same issue with the bsp version I used.

Comment: In that case I'd ask the vendor to provide a solution. And as for here: As "not booting up" and "not detected by ADB" are two separate issues, better keep them separate. It's irritating if the question asks for one, and you're primarily looking for the other ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the developer options again after doing a factory reset?If not follow the below steps to enable it.

Go to Settings, About phone and tap on build number 7 times to unlock/enable Developer options again (factory reset would've put it back to the default of locked/disabled).

Enable USB debugging from the developer options after the above step for adb/fastboot to work.

Comment: Thank you for prompt replay, After i click the factory reset option on android the device is not booting up. if the device detected i can load new image